# Autoplay vimeo working on 2 domains but not a 3rd

Tags: video, vimeo, autoplay

The 3rd domain is https. I tried another https domain and it appeared to work although it's late, the site launch went ahead but without the video so I'll test more tomorrow.

Is there any sane reason to think the domain could be creating the issue? Same server, same code (just changed the binding).

The vimeo page on autoplaying has nothing on https:

https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004485728-Autoplaying-and-looping-embedded-videos

Answer (score 0):

Turns out another video was playing in the background and the vimeo settings were making it load only on the domain having the issue. So another video was cutting off the autoplaying video.